# How to validate an element using bValidator

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

For ex:

I have two elements in form as given below.

Alphabetic characters only:

```
        <p>
            <input id="lname" data-bvalidator="alphanum,required" type="text">
        </p>
```

My requirement is, onblur of each element I need to save the value into database.

So, I can use ValidateOn:'blur', onAfterElementValidation settings and if element is valid I can save the data. But when I submit the form, again its validating and trying to save the data.

In jQuery Validator, we can validate an element like

$('#fname').isValid()

same as I would like to know is there any option in bValidtor to validate an elements individually.

Answer (score 2):

In bValidator you can validate an element individually like this:

```
$('#yourFormID').data('bValidator').validate(false, $('#fname'))
```

look at the validate() function in the documentation:
http://karmela.fsb.hr/~bmauser/bvalidator/documentation.html#validate.
With first argument (true/false) you controll display of error message tooltip.

And as of version 0.52 you can check if element is valid with:

```
$('#yourFormID').data('bValidator').isValid($('#fname'))
```